# Finding Maximum value of KL- Divergence between functions of probability distribution.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

**PROBLEM** :-

$p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ are probability distibutions over $R^2$.
They are analytical functions.

Let $f(x') = \iint p(x)p(x'|y)p(y|x)dx\ dy$

and

$g(x') = \iint p(x)q(x'|y)q(y|x)dx\ dy$

What is the maximum possible value of 
$D_{KL}( f(x') || g(x') )$  given,

$D_{KL}( p(x,y) || q(x,y) ) \leq x_{0}$.

where $x_{0}$ is a positive constant.

I was trying to solve above problem but could not sadly. One of the results I derived on the way was  :-

$ D_{KL}( p(x,y)||q(x,y) ) = D_{KL}( p(x) || q(x) )
                             + Ex_{p(x)}[ D_{KL}( p(y|x)||q(y|x) ]$

$=D_{KL}( p(y)||q(y) ) + Ex_{p(y)}[ D_{KL}( p(x|y) || q(x|y) ]$

Also, that $f(x) = p(x)$

But I can't seem to make any headway anymore, for quite some time now.. Please help.

Comment: In the definition of $g(x')$, is it really a $p(x)$ (not $q(x)$) in the integrand?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes. It is what it is.

Comment: @ClementC. Even if you make little progress, please let me know..